# Justifying a string followed by a number

Tags: java, beginner, formatting

I started practicing on HackerRank to see how my learning is going on with Java. 
I wrote this code for problem which involved input having:

> 1. String with maximum length of 10, followed by
> 2. A 3 digit or lesser integer

Examples: `"java 100"`, `"Amazing 98"`

Expected output:

> 1. String should be left-justified with trailing white spaces till 15th character
> 2. Leading digit of integer starts at 16th place with leading zeroes if it is less than 3 digits(padding) to make up for 18 characters

Examples: `"java           100"`, `"Amazing        098"`

```
package HackerRank;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IOFormatting {
    public ArrayList<String> getAllLines(){
        ArrayList<String> allInputs = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner getIp = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(getIp.hasNext()) {
            allInputs.add(getIp.nextLine());
        }
        getIp.close();
        return allInputs;
    }

    public ArrayList<Character> getTheInputAsArrayList(String input) {
        ArrayList<Character> inputLine = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(int itr1=0;itr1<input.length();itr1++) {
            inputLine.add(input.charAt(itr1));
        }
        return inputLine;
    }

    public ArrayList<Character> formatTheArrayList(ArrayList<Character> inputLine){
        int itr2 = getBreakPoint(inputLine);
        for(int itr3=itr2+1;itr3<15;itr3++) {
            inputLine.add(itr3,' ');
        }
        return inputLine;
    }

    public int getBreakPoint(ArrayList<Character> inputLine){
        for(int itr2=0;itr2<=10;itr2++) {
            if(inputLine.get(itr2) == ' ') {
                return itr2;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public ArrayList<Character> doIntegerPadding(ArrayList<Character> inputLine){
        int padSize = 18 - inputLine.size();
        if(padSize>0) {
            for(int itr4=15;itr4<=14+padSize;itr4++) {
                inputLine.add(itr4,'0');
            }
        }
        return inputLine;
    }

    public String convertToFinalString(ArrayList<Character> inputLine) {
        String outputString = "";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (Character s : inputLine) {
             sb.append(s);
        }
        outputString = sb.toString();
        return outputString;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        IOFormatting io = new IOFormatting();
        ArrayList<String> allInputs = io.getAllLines();
        System.out.println("================================");
        for(int mainItr=0;mainItr<allInputs.size();mainItr++) {
            String input = allInputs.get(mainItr);
            ArrayList<Character> inputLine = io.getTheInputAsArrayList(input);
            inputLine = io.formatTheArrayList(inputLine);
            inputLine = io.doIntegerPadding(inputLine);
            String outputString = io.convertToFinalString(inputLine);
            System.out.println(outputString);
        }
        System.out.println("================================");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are vastly overcomplicating the solution.  The `Scanner` is perfectly capable of reading a string and an integer separately.  Then, it is a simple matter of calling [`System.out.printf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%27java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...%28) with the appropriate width specifications:

- `%-15s` for a string, left-justified, with trailing spaces
- `%03d` for an integer, zero-padded

Also, `Scanner` is [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), so you should use a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block instead of calling `.close()` on it manually.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IOFormatting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                System.out.printf("%-15s%03d%n", input.next(), input.nextInt());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you really wanted to do the formatting the hard way by inserting spaces and zeroes, I suggest editing each line using [`StringBuilder.insert()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert%27int,char%28) — your `ArrayList<Character>` is a rather unnatural way to edit a string.

Comment: Great!!, I've got new stuff to read. Moreover, I wanted someone to tell me what you just did : "Unnatural"